# R & XML - assign data to correct parent nodes which are equally named in a dataframe

Tags: xml, r

I want to extract specific data from an XML file to an R dataframe. I want to use the data later on to reconstruct digitalized pen strokes by an Anoto Pen.
So far I'm doing this by using the library **rvest**.
(Example XML file can be found below)

```
library(rvest)

file <- read_xml("1.xml")

#The interesting data is in the stroke nodes.
stroke <- xml_nodes(file, "stroke")

#One example for extracting data I am interested in.
bounds <- xml_nodes(stroke, "bounds")
x <- xml_text(xml_nodes(bounds, "x"))
y <- xml_text(xml_nodes(bounds, "y"))
width <- xml_text(xml_nodes(bounds, "width"))
height <- xml_text(xml_nodes(bounds, "height"))

#Putting this data into a Dataframe.
df <- data.frame(x, y, width, height)
```

So far so good. My problem now are the `<sample>` nodes. I have a minimum number of one `<stroke>` node in the XML files, going up to approx. 100 at max. Each `<stroke>` node has its own `<sample>` nodes. I want to extract the x-,y-, and time-data from the sample nodes in a way I can assign them to the corresponding stroke in the dataframe. 
For example, if I just do

```
mysamples <- xml_nodes(stroke, "sample")
```

I receive all samples from all strokes, but I have to distinguish between different strokes.
I thought about writing a function making use of a for-loop to iterate over the different strokes, but I could not get this going.

Here is a shortened XML file sample with two `<stroke>` nodes.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<page>
  <UnassignedStrokes>
    <starttime>1459867893629</starttime>
    <endtime>1459867896812</endtime>
    <stroke>
      <starttime>1459867893629</starttime>
      <endtime>1459867894815</endtime>
      <linewidth>1.0</linewidth>
      <color>-14090101</color>
      <bounds>
        <x>260.0</x>
        <y>750.0</y>
        <width>217.0</width>
        <height>18.0</height>
      </bounds>
      <sample>
        <x>260.625</x>
        <y>766.0</y>
        <time>1459867893629</time>
        <force>108</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>260.625</x>
        <y>763.625</y>
        <time>1459867893722</time>
        <force>120</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>262.875</x>
        <y>762.0</y>
        <time>1459867893775</time>
        <force>122</force>
      </sample>
    </stroke>
    <stroke>
      <starttime>1459867895892</starttime>
      <endtime>1459867896812</endtime>
      <linewidth>1.0</linewidth>
      <color>-14090101</color>
      <bounds>
        <x>364.0</x>
        <y>701.0</y>
        <width>10.0</width>
        <height>125.0</height>
      </bounds>
      <sample>
        <x>364.5</x>
        <y>701.0</y>
        <time>1459867895892</time>
        <force>32</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>366.0</x>
        <y>702.0</y>
        <time>1459867895905</time>
        <force>106</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>367.25</x>
        <y>702.625</y>
        <time>1459867895958</time>
        <force>120</force>
      </sample>
    </stroke>
  </UnassignedStrokes>
</page>
```

I highly appreciate any help!

Comment: Currently your bounds dataframe does not capture stroke. Do you require two dataframes: bounds and sample with stroke data identified as columns? In XML, both are siblings to each other. Please show desired end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will generate a single dataframe linking together the "bounds" dataframe with the sample information from all of the children nodes.  It is a bit rough around the edges by it works:

```
#Putting this data into a Dataframe.
df<-data.frame(x, y, width, height, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#list of of subnodes
samples<-sapply(stroke, FUN=xml_nodes, xpath="sample")
#find list of lists for x, y, time and force from each subnode of interest
sx<-sapply(samples, FUN=function(x) {xml_text(xml_nodes(x, xpath="x"))})
sy<-sapply(samples, FUN=function(x) {xml_text(xml_nodes(x, xpath="y"))})
stime<-sapply(samples, FUN=function(x) {xml_text(xml_nodes(x, xpath="time"))})
sforce<-sapply(samples, FUN=function(x) {xml_text(xml_nodes(x, xpath="force"))})

#create dataframe from the parent df and the list of lists of subnodes
results<-lapply(seq(1:length(sx)), function(i){data.frame(df[i,],sx=unlist(sx[i]), 
        sy=unlist(sy[i]), force=unlist(sforce[i]), time=unlist(stime[i]),
                                                              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)})
#create a single df
finaldf<-do.call(rbind, results)
#convert all columns to numeric values
finaldf[,1:ncol(finaldf)]<-lapply(finaldf[,1:ncol(finaldf)], as.numeric)
```

This will generate a few warnings, but those can be ignored.  For the do.call(rbind) to work it is important that the values throughout the process are either numeric or characters and not factors, thus the stringsAsFactors=FALSE parameters in data.frame definitions.
This was a good learning experience.

Comment: This worked great for me! Thanks! Even though the as.numeric function makes my time values convert to sth like 1.523526e+12 values, which is not so nice... have an idea how to prevent this?

Comment: With numbers this large they are most likely the number of milli seconds from the beginning of time Jan 1, 1970, according to UNIX.  I would divide by 1000 and plug into: as.POSIXct(x, origin = "1970-01-01").  You may have to adjust for the time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is an easier way, but this is the best solution I've come up with:

```
require(rvest)
require(data.table)

strokes <- read_xml("test.xml") %>% xml_nodes("stroke")

# iterate over stroke nodes
tmp <- lapply(strokes, function(x){

  # get all sample nodes
  samples <- x %>% xml_nodes("sample")  

  # iterate over samples in stroke and extract information
  tmp.s <- lapply(samples, function(s){
    children <- xml_children(s)
    data.frame(name = xml_name(children), text = xml_text(children))
  })

  # bind samples together and give them the appropriate ID
  tmp.s <- rbindlist(tmp.s, idcol = "sample")
  tmp.s
})

# bind strokes together and give them the appropriate ID
tmp <- rbindlist(tmp, idcol = "stroke")

tmp
    stroke sample  name          text
 1:      1      1     x       260.625
 2:      1      1     y         766.0
 3:      1      1  time 1459867893629
 4:      1      1 force           108
 5:      1      2     x       260.625
 6:      1      2     y       763.625
 7:      1      2  time 1459867893722
 8:      1      2 force           120
 9:      1      3     x       262.875
10:      1      3     y         762.0
11:      1      3  time 1459867893775
12:      1      3 force           122
13:      2      1     x         364.5
14:      2      1     y         701.0
15:      2      1  time 1459867895892
16:      2      1 force            32
17:      2      2     x         366.0
18:      2      2     y         702.0
19:      2      2  time 1459867895905
20:      2      2 force           106
21:      2      3     x        367.25
22:      2      3     y       702.625
23:      2      3  time 1459867895958
24:      2      3 force           120
    stroke sample  name          text
```

Hope this helps!